# Data being dropped out of histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I'm trying to make a simple histogram showing the number of fish entering a system by date. Fish are entering the system via two locations and I want to have the bars of the histogram colored for each station. However, when I add the fill aesthetic, the data for July 7th (the only entry from station A) gets deleted. This is how it looks without the fill aesthetic...

[image]

And this is with the fill...[image]

Here's my code without fill:

```
  geom_histogram(aes(monthday), stat = 'count') +
  theme_bw() + labs(x = "Date", y = "Fish Entry") + theme(axis.text = element_text( size = 12))
```

And With:

```
  geom_histogram(aes(monthday, fill = Station2), stat = 'count') +
  theme_bw() + labs(x = "Date", y = "Fish Entry") + theme(axis.text = element_text( size = 12))
```

The dataframe "first" has two columns: monthday(POSIXct, y-m-d), and Station2 (Factor A,G)

Here's my data in ASCII:

```
structure(list(monthday = structure(c(1529539200, 1529625600, 
1529625600, 1529712000, 1529712000, 1529798400, 1529798400, 1529884800, 
1529884800, 1529971200, 1529971200, 1529971200, 1529971200, 1529971200, 
1529971200, 1529971200, 1529971200, 1529971200, 1530057600, 1530057600, 
1530057600, 1530057600, 1530057600, 1530057600, 1530057600, 1530144000, 
1530230400, 1530230400, 1530316800, 1530403200, 1530489600, 1530921600
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "GMT"), Station2 = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("A", 
"G"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(43424L, 
43504L, 43774L, 43778L, 44055L, 44327L, 44328L, 44511L, 44677L, 
44796L, 44830L, 44921L, 44942L, 45373L, 45394L, 45449L, 45817L, 
45825L, 46104L, 46106L, 46625L, 47214L, 47229L, 47389L, 47544L, 
50186L, 52027L, 54694L, 55437L, 61670L, 67598L, 96186L))
```

Comment: please include the data so others can replicate your problem. Use `dput` to put the data into an easily imported format

Comment: `dput(first)` and copy/paste the output `structure()`

Comment: Depending on how your data is formatted, a bar chart may better represent your desired result the a histogram. Please check the help for  `geom_bar` or `geom_col`

Comment: I had the same thought as Dave2e, but switching to `ggplot(df) + 
  geom_bar(aes(monthday, fill = Station2))` still replicates the problem. Strange!

Comment: Just a comment because I don't understand **why** (and I don't have time to investigate and answer now---anyone else, feel free), but converting the POSIX to Date fixes the issue. `ggplot(df) +  geom_bar(aes(as.Date(monthday), fill = Station2))` works fine.

Comment: if you change `fill = Station2` to `color = Station2` you actually see `A`...very strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick hack in the meantime would be to do:

```
ggplot(first,aes(x=as.Date(monthday), fill = Station2))+
geom_histogram(stat = 'count') +
theme_bw() + labs(x = "Date", y = "Fish Entry") + 
theme(axis.text = element_text( size = 12))
```

[image]

I think you need `as.Date(monthday)` because when you change `monthday` to Date, it treats the input as a whole day (which POSIXct might treat as just a small portion of that day). Because the x-axis is continuous, the width of the bar for `A` is so narrow that it isn't being shown on the plot when you use `fill = Station2`. Not 100% sure why `fill` causes `A` to disappear, but this workaround should be helpful.